# Wordpress Resource Usage

Tags: wordpress, performance, optimization

I am trying to optimize a Wordpress at his best.
What I have done up to now :

- WP-Cron disabled, called through a cron-tab query (every 10 min)
- Disabled all plugins that aren't needed
- Installed / configured WP Super Cache together with WP Minify
- Disabled Revisions (but then re-enabled it because I was getting empty posts (strange)
- Put a subdomain as a CDN for images and scripts

here is a classic report of Resource Usage on my control panel :

```
    57.0% .../index.php () 
    7.0%  php -q ../wp-cron.php () 
    5.0%  httpd (...)
```

Specs :

- Around 5000 unique visitors / day

I would like to avoid moving to a dedicated server (this a shared hosting) or at least try everything I can before having to move.... any idea?

Comment: How many unique visitors per day?

Comment: What are the specs on your server? How many reqs/sec do you have, especially at peak times?

Comment: Ahmad : I added the information in the post
@doublesharp As it is a shared hosting, I don't have much information about the server. Do you know I way that would allow me to access information you ask?

Comment: I would expect them to be able to tell them something about what you are paying for... just because it is shared doesn't mean you can't be guaranteed some level of resources. You Resource Usage panel has to be relative to something.

Comment: With 5k uv/day, I think you should moving to dedicated server or vps at least.

Comment: Well I guess you are right :(

Answer (score 0):

I use the Total Cache plugin, the free version and it works very fine. I don't have problems with new posts.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/

This plugin does everything also minify html,javascript and css

Comment: Hi, I never had problem with WP Super Cache on many sites, but are you telling me that Total Cache would be better on performance?

Comment: For me it is very fast and it have many options to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Ahmad Suhendri, dedicated server was a good idea. I moved to a dedicated server and now the website is very fast.